# In My Webview Upload Image Button Not Working But In Browser It's Working

Tags: android, flutter, performance, android-studio, woocommerce

In My Webview Upload Image Button Not Working But In Browser It's Working .Using WordPress file upload not working using flutter.rest all working fine

used all permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Do i need add something in main dart file

Comment: Perhaps you need permission in the WebView to execute JavaScript.

Comment: @VijayS Not working any other workaround using flutter